# resetting and "if" statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I am having trouble resetting and if statement to capture the correct input into the command:

If you select '2', if it will ask you again. If you respond 'L', it will capture that as a valid command, however the 'Letter' variable will still be stored as the original input '2'. How do I reset the first command to take the second?

```
# Letters is captured in a list A-Z

def choose_letter(question):
    Letter = input('choose a letter:')
    if Letter not in Letters:
        print('Please choose a valid Letter. A-Z.')
        choose_letter(question)
    else:
        return Letter
```

Comment: replace the call to `choose_letter(question)` with `return choose_letter(question)`

Answer (score 2):

You should return `choose_letter`, otherwise the recursive call does not bring anything.

```
# Letters is captured in a list A-Z

def choose_letter(question):
        Letter = input('choose a letter:')
        if Letter not in Letters:
          print('Please choose a valid Letter. A-Z.')
          return choose_letter(question)
        else:
          return Letter
```

Also note that it might be better to rename your Letter variable to, say, userInput, since it is not a letter yet. And instead of using a list, you could consider using a regex to figure out if the input is indeed a letter.

Comment: any reason why this would work in python tutor but fail in repl.it ? This works in my simulator in python tutor but still brings up an error in repl.it

Comment: Or Letters could be a string